# CPU Usage Avoid 100% With Environment.ProcessorCount?

Tags: c#, cpu

I would like to know if this will work to avoid 100% of CPU usage.

Environment.ProcessorCount will get back Logical Processors Count, In my case i7 4 real cores 8 logical. In some other cases it can differently. But what matters is CPU usage. If I use my application to use Environment.ProcessorCount cores it will use 100% on my PC. What if I do

> string lesscpu = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;

So baisclly removing 1 core. On my PC it will be 7 cores and around 80-90% CPU usage.
in some other cases:

2 cores 2 logical = 1 = 50% cpu

2 cores 4 logical = 3 = 70%+ cpu

2 cores 6 logical = 5 = 70%+ cpu

is this true?

UPDATE:

This heavy lifting happens when I'm idle the program will switch off to 1 thread when I'm back...
I afraid that if I leave it for long hours on 100% CPU on all cores my pc can overheat and restart or even worse?...

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with CPU Utilization and CPU Cores? No. of cores do not directly convert to CPU Utilization. I mean, `((Used Count) / (Total Count))% !~ CPU Utilization %`

Comment: @theghostofc what only if we talk about total count, I dont want to look for used count :) Will this still theoretically work?

Comment: This definitely seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @PeakDermutag, I don't think so, IMHO.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I just want to know if this kind of logic is true... like theghostofc said It's more complex than that and I understand that. But i wonder if this logic works... the soultion can really be getting the real core numbers but this function is so bugged and doesn't work on all PC's that I better risk it and use this logic than CPU Cores. Also thanks for the link its useful :)

Comment: @theghostofc why not? if my program uses equal amount of CPU power each core should be used by 100% if total 4 cores 2 core on 100% = total cpu at 50%...The real question here if logical count is always accurate

Answer (score 4):

There is *very* little point in buying a nice processor and then not using its capabilities.  If you observe 100% cpu utilization then you can be confident in doing it **right**.  You get what you paid for *and* you wrote a program that gets maximum concurrency out of the threads.  Good job.

The only possible mistake you could make is not lowering the Thread.Priority.  Which is important if you care that *other* programs don't become sluggish when they compete for the processor.

Comment: Another 30% of the CPU that is not used could just as well be used for something else if he needs to.

Comment: Kinda pointless, in most cases that just goes unused and only makes the program run slower.  A 100% of the CPU can be used by *all* programs.  The operating system schedules threads by priority.  Covered in any introductory book on OS design btw.

Comment: Sometimes you want your PC to do some heavy lifting while still being able to do other tasks like say - answering questions on SO or browsing Facebook. :) You're right though- 100% CPU would be more effective!

Comment: This heavy lifting happens when I'm idle the program will switch off to 1 thread when I'm back...
I afraid that if I leave it for long hours on 100% CPU on all cores my pc can overheat and restart or even worse?...

Comment: This kind of myth is impossible to reason with.  It's an attractive market opportunity perhaps, somebody could make a decent living selling fire extinguishers labelled "for PC use and even worse" at 200% markup.

Comment: @PeakDermutag Modern CPUs can not over-heat, so there isn't a *even worse* scenario regarding CPUs.  There are thermal limits that either cause the CPU to slow down (thus losing heat instead of gaining heat) or they turn off completely.  If you're worried about this scenario then the program isn't at fault, the problem lies with  the computer case/heat dissipation design.

Comment: Here's a [fun video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSGcnRanYMM) where they overheat processors intentionally by taking the cooler off.  It is old, AMD got a pretty good ding out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SO Question [How to get the CPU Usage in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278071/1654121). You may also set the priority of the threads as mentioned in SO [How to restrict the CPU usage a C# program takes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/251220/1654121) You may want to review [CPU Usage with graphical indication using C# .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442797/CPU-Usage-with-graphical-indication-using-Csharp-N) too.